# TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index', but my index is a DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have some time series data that is measured hourly, I want to average the values over different resolutions by resampling. I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

The head of the dataframe is as follows:

```
 DateTimeUtc       DK1  ...        SE3        SE4
DateTimeUtc                                         ...                      
2022-01-01 00:00:00  2022-01-01 00:00:00  1691.712  ... -112.99925   93.56625
2022-01-01 01:00:00  2022-01-01 01:00:00  1244.341  ...   68.27500  345.15800
2022-01-01 02:00:00  2022-01-01 02:00:00   927.078  ...  308.46300  648.40400
2022-01-01 03:00:00  2022-01-01 03:00:00   612.140  ...
```

Maybe its not clear in the formatting, but I have set the index as the DateTimeUtc column and then kept a copy of this column for now, using the following lines:

```
import pandas as pd
path = r'C:\Users\ERROR_2022.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Unnamed: 0', 'DateTimeUtc') # necessary formatting
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTimeUtc']))
```

From this post:

[TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex' and I can't figure out why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703538/typeerror-only-valid-with-datetimeindex-timedeltaindex-or-periodindex-but-got)

I steal the idea as I want to resample then make some summary statistics with the results, as I need to take a column in df rather than the whole thing, like so:

```
weekly_summary = df.resample('W', on='DateTimeUtc')['DK1'].sum()
```

But the error persists, can anyone can help?

--Last minute addition--

Furthermore, I have tried dropping the `'DateTimeUtc'` column and running the above line of code again and i get a different error

```
KeyError: 'The grouper name DateTimeUtc is not found'
```

Cracked it with the following addition,

```
df.drop('DateTimeUtc', axis = 1, inplace = True)
#%% Resampling
daily_summary = df.resample('D')['DK1'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to set the DateTimeUtc column as an index. As long as there is a column that exists with that name

```
weekly_summary = df.resample('W', on='DateTimeUtc')['DK1'].sum()
```

this should work. The `KeyError` generally means that there is no column with that name.

The first error occurs because by default, resample will work on the index of a dataframe. And if the index is not a DateTimeIndex, TimeDeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, it will give you that error. When you create a dataframe and dont specify a particular index value, it defaults to an integer based RangeIndex. And the `resample` function only works on those particular index types.

to replicate your dataframe and solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['DateTimeUTC', 'DTC'])
df['DateTimeUTC'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=24, freq='H')
df['DTC'] = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(24)]
df.resample('W', on='DateTimeUTC')['DTC'].sum()
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, your solution doesn't work for me, but it helped, I found by setting the index and dropping the DatetimeUtc column finally worked